# gcloud app SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, gcloud

I have created laravel application with database it run on localhost so i decide to deploy on GCP appengine but when i click on deploy this happen 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
i connecting to my GCP sql Instance below are my app.yaml

1st i use local host that uses sql_proxy it show no files directory then i remove the DB_Socket then this error come out SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

## Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development

skip_files:
  - .env

env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: base64:G9druqluKMZ6TugSgmM1OJVwWSzfstc08acMRBAqxwg=
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  SESSION_DRIVER: database
  ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
  DB_HOST: 35.231.242.40
  DB_DATABASE: lkcfes
  DB_USERNAME: root
  DB_PASSWORD:

Answer (score 0):

This question is more appropriate for a [support case](https://support.google.com/googlecloud/answer/1041916?hl=en) so that a Google Cloud Platform support agent can inspect your app.yaml and Cloud SQL instance.

Having said that, there is a guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible) on running Laravel on GAE Flex. You'll find it includes using a "beta_settings" section on your yaml, the Cloud SQL instance's public IP is not used.